# how to convert maven project to web project in myeclipse?

Tags: maven, web

I have a project at here:

https://github.com/ZhibingXie/SpringMVC-Spring-Hibernate

I have tried to import this project into myeclipse and convert it to web project, but I failed to do this.

I have searched a lot from the internet,most of the answers tell me to modify the settings in Project Facets. But I can't find this.

```
Myeclipse verision: Enterprise Workbench Version: 8.5
```

Comment: Can you tell me your myeclipse version?

Comment: MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench

Version: 8.5
like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your myeclipse version is low that make you can not find some settings.

I used:

```
MyEclipse Enterprise Workbench Version: 2015 CI
```

I can use the settings below to convert maven project to web project:

```
Project -> Properties -> My Eclipse -> Project Facets -> Dynamic Web Module
```

Make this option selected.